# Do King Benny and Fat Man know the whole story?

Tags: plot-explanation, sleepers

In the film [Sleepers](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117665/) (1996), do Fat Man and King Benny know the whole story about what happened to the boys (rapes, beatings, etc.)?

They seem to know everything, and they're going along with the scam taking place against the Wilkinson School for Boys, but I thought that the four boys had never told anyone all the details.

Answer (score 2):

King Benny definitely knows of the beatings, because when he sold Addison's debt to Little Ceasar he mentions that the person who now owes him the money is the person who killed his little brother.

Answer (score 0):

Also many of hell's kitchens residents had served time there and knew from personal experience of the horrors attributed to Wilkinsons. More than likely king Benny had heard the rumors or had witnessed them himself. Father bobby mentions he had a friend whose time at Wilkinsons turned him dead inside, the title/term sleepers was referenced as the term for anyone who had served time in Wilkinsons and also referenced as being "king Benny's sleepers" so its possible king Benny was also a victim of Wilkinsons pedophilia scandal.